# How to get Intent result launched in a different class using ActivityResultRegistry?

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I have an Intent that is launched from a method that cannot be modified.
Something like this:

```
public static void launchIntent() { ... }
```

What is the **updated methodology** of handling the Intent's result with `ActivityResultRegistry` in the class (a fragment) that calls `launchIntent()`?

Background:

Would normally use `onActivityResult` since the `request` int IS KNOWN, but was wondering if there is a way to do this with ActivityResultRegistry since `onActivityResult` is deprecated?

Current Implementation:

```
public class SomeClass extends Fragment {

  public void onSomeEvent {
    AnotherClass.launchIntent();
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent i){
    if (request == Constants.LaunchIntentCode){
      // handle the result once AnotherClass.launchIntent() returns
    }
  }
}

Trying to see if something like this was possible (the code below is invalid since `launchIntent` is `void` return and not a contract):
```

final ActivityResultLauncher intentResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult( SomeClass.launchIntent(),
result -> { ... });
intentResultLauncher.launch()

Comment: Show complete code please to begin with so we can test your problem.

Comment: From what I understand, the ActivityResultRegistry does not support this use case currently.